# Rotate UIView iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, rotation

I am working on a puzzle game and I need to rotate the puzzle pieces to `90` degrees angle on every double tap.

I have tried to do did using two different ways. First method is this one:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The only problems with that are that the piece is NOT rotating `90` degrees; it is rotating by around `100` degrees, and that this animation is modifying the frame of the puzzle piece `UIView`.

This is my console output:

```
frame BEFORE ROTATION: {{35, 178}, {80, 80}}

frame AFTER ROTATION: {{21.3172, 164.317}, {107.366, 107.366}}
```

The second method I tried was this one:

```
CABasicAnimation* spinAnimation = [CABasicAnimation
                                       animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
spinAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];
[self.layer addAnimation:spinAnimation forKey:@"spinAnimation"];
```

The problem with this method is that after finishing the rotation, it is reversing my `UIView` to its previous state.

How can I rotate the puzzle piece with an animation without having these problems?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

where you can define DegreesToRadians as

```
#define DegreesToRadians(x) ((x) * M_PI / 180.0)
```

Comment: It's not actually animating for me, it's just switching between the two rotation states...

Answer (score 5):

Your first method is good, exept the angle is in radian

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90/180*M_PI);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 4):

Most everyone is now using animation blocks for iOS animating. So a little something like this is what I would recommend (of course you can set your own timing and animation options and degrees to rotate). Enjoy

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        YOURVIEW.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(180));
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

#define DegreesToRadians(x) ((x) * M_PI / 180.0)
```

if you are looking for a 360 degree turn that is a bit more tricky since it doesn't want to animate a rotation of what will end up being exactly where it started so use something like this:

```
- (void)rotateSpinningView:(UIView *)viewToSpin{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        [viewToSpin setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(viewToSpin.transform, M_PI_2)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished && !CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(viewToSpin.transform, CGAffineTransformIdentity)) {
            [self rotateSpinningView:viewToSpin];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I this the best way is to declare C function

```
static inline CGFloat degreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees) {return (degrees) * M_PI / 180.0f;}
```

and the use it like this

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rotate" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(180.0f));
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Just to clarify, a definition is faster then a c function. Because of that MAX, MIN, ABS are definitions too.