# iPhone: draw the objects along the curve

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, drawing, uilabel, curve

Good day, friends.

There is a task: to draw repeating objects (UIImageView and UILabel) along the curve (if more exactly, it's an arc).

What classes should be used for it?

Comment: What do you mean with "what classes should be used for it?" All you need to do is to calculate the points on the arc and position your views. Do you have trouble with calculating the points ?

Comment: When I do the same task in Android SDK, I may use android.graphics.Path to draw the path and then position views along it. Is any similar in iPhone SDK?

Comment: Is there some example ? Because `android.graphics.Path` looks almost exactly like `UIBezierPath`, I can't see any methods/features that aid with the positioning of views.

Comment: Then, the question is, how to draw views with specific angles?

Comment: http://s53.radikal.ru/i141/1108/23/33b90459b9ad.png
I have PNGs for red fragments, as you can see, they have different angles. How to "rotate" them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to Android's `Path`, you can use either [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) or [CGPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html). The former is Objective-C, the later pure C. I recommend going with UIBezierPath as it's easier to use.

To rotate a view, use the [`transform` property of UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457122/rotate-uiview-iphone) for an example on how to use it). But note that you then need to ignore the `frame` (it's undefined) and need to move the view by modifying the [`center`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/center) instead.

Comment: OK, I'll try it and report the results.