# How can i draw arc with Core Graphics and how can i rotate that arc

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to draw an arc using Core Graphics and i want to rotate that arc.I tried building the arc in this way

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 500);
//    CGContextAddCurveTopoPoint(context, 0, 500, 50, 90, 180, 1);
    CGContextAddArc(context, 60, 500, 50, 90, 180, 0);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

And i want to rotate this arc. Can any one help me how can i do this animation  Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103510/iphone-draw-the-objects-along-the-curve

Comment: This is not what i am looking for. Any way thanks!

Comment: The accepted answer on the linked question _is_ what you are looking for. You can draw the arc in a view, then rotate the view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rotating view you can try to use CGAffineTranform.
Or rotate each point manually via multiplying points' coordiates on a matrix which look likes:

```
| cos x   sin x |
| -sin x  cos x |
```