# Draw UILabel or NSString along path

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, uilabel, cgrect

First day on a new job, I've been asked to help out on an iPad app. They have asked me to draw an NSString along a curved path (the curve is sort of like an S shape).

Not really sure how to do this without looping through the letters of the string and drawing each letter individually after rotating and moving it's frame. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
-(void)doCurveString:(NSString *)stringToCurve{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(768, 1024));


    NSArray *arrayFullOfCGRects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(300, 500, 20, 20)],
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(315, 510, 20, 20)],
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(330, 500, 20, 20)],
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(345, 510, 20, 20)],
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(360, 500, 20, 20)],
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(375, 510, 20, 20)],
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(390, 500, 20, 20)],
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(405, 510, 20, 20)],
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(420, 500, 20, 20)],
                                   [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(435, 510, 20, 20)],
                                   nil];

    NSArray *arrayFullOfRotateTransforms = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/1)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/1)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/3)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/5)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/6)],
                                            [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/1)],
                                            nil];

    NSDictionary *drawDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    arrayFullOfCGRects, @"frames",
                                    arrayFullOfRotateTransforms, @"rotations",
                                    nil];

    for(NSInteger charIndex=0; charIndex<stringToCurve.length; charIndex++){

        //Create a label and set it's frame coordinates
        UILabel *labelToDraw = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:[[[drawDictionary objectForKey:@"frames"] objectAtIndex:charIndex] CGRectValue]];

        //Rotate the letter with the transform stored in the array
        labelToDraw.transform = [[[drawDictionary objectForKey:@"rotations"] objectAtIndex:charIndex] CGAffineTransformValue];

        //Set the label text to the letter at the correct index
        labelToDraw.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [stringToCurve characterAtIndex:charIndex]];

        //Make sure the background colour is transparent
        labelToDraw.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        //Draw it to the view controller view
        [self.view addSubview:labelToDraw];

    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

There has to be a better way surely? A drawTextOnPath:someCGPath method that I don't know about/can't find?

Comment: [Your question has been answered before (here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103510/iphone-draw-the-objects-along-the-curve) [and here, for example)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841642/curve-text-on-existing-circle) (and I hope this helps you!)

Comment: Yeah seen both. Think the second is a bit advanced for my level of ability at the moment. That first link is brief too. Thanks anyway.