# Change origin in iPad landscape

Tags: ios, coordinates, uiinterfaceorientation

In my iPad app I set the supported interface orientations only to both landscape modes.
I have a UIView with the background color set to red and I initialise it with `frame x:0 y:706 w:1024 h:60`.

The red UIView doesn't appear where I want. The origin will be in the TOP-RIGHT corner (as if the iPad is still in portrait orientation mode), even if the iPad simulator starts in landscape mode. I want the origin to change to the TOP-LEFT corner when in landscape mode.
How can I do this? I have to mention that I'm new to working with different landscape modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line @iPhoneDeveloper has already said It starts in Portait mode and then rotate to Landscape.

you can set coordinates like it is portrait and set autoresizingMask of your view, so your view will be resized and placed for landscape

or

you can override the following method in your view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

and set the frames of your subviews. 
The method get called after all rotations.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever iOS app starts, it default orientation stays portrait if you have setup both landscape orientations. You can show your UIView in top-right corner by transforming it.

see here [Rotate UIView iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457122/rotate-uiview-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to know the device orientation is to check the statusbar orientation:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation))...
```

this way you can put your button in the right spot.