# UIView will not rotate?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I am trying to rotate a `UIView`, maybe i am doing something very stupid, but i can't seems to rotate that simple view :

```
 menuPointer=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(k*width, height, 50, 50)];
    menuPointer.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    menuPointer.backgroundColor=upperView.backgroundColor;
    [upperView addSubview:menuPointer];
```

What happens is that i see a `rect`, at the right size, but not rotated .
Do i need to import something like `Quartz` ?

Comment: Width of the view is equal to its height, how do you know whether it rotate.

Comment: you don't have a content inside the view, but the solid background color... so, if you rotate a _square_ `(50.f, 50.f)` by `M_PI/2` it will be identical to the original one, because it is a _square_ and that rotation will transform it into its original 'state' around its center. that is just elementary geometry, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
menuPointer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(90));
#define DegreesToRadians(x) ((x) * M_PI / 180.0)
```

Found here: [Link!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457122/rotate-uiview-iphone)